# Problems with SORT_FLAG_CASE flag

Tags: php

I am tring to do (like) a 2 dimensional array, case insensitive.

I have:

```
foreach ($rows as $key=>$row) { 
    $names[$key]=$row['Name']; 
} 

array_multisort($rows,SORT_STRING|SORT_FLAG_CASE,$names);
```

The above ends up producing the same result (with or without case flag).

Sick of staring at this, any ideas from somebody outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all **SORT_FLAG_CASE** is only available in PHP v5.4+ so I suggest checking which version of PHP you are running (maybe '**uksort**' could help if 5.3ish).

If not, make sure all the values that you put into **$names** lowercase or uppercase.

You have the order of the arguements **$rows** and **$names** reversed in the call to **array_multisort**.

Lastly if it comes from a database (or some other manner that means you cant change the data on the way into the array) then you can use **array_walk**.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Since I ran into this with PHP 5.3.16, I thought I'd share my simple solution: just convert your keys to lower (or upper) case, e.g.:

```
foreach ($rows as $key=>$row) { 
    $names[$key]=strtolower($row['Name']); 
} 

array_multisort($names,SORT_STRING,$rows);
```

I also swapped the `$rows` & `$names` and removed the `SORT_FLAG_CASE` (to get rid of the log message).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a sort within a sort, so you can use usort with strcasecmp:

```
foreach ($rows as $key=>$row) { 
    $names[$key]=row['Name']; 
} 

array_multisort(usort($names,strcasecmp),$rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer didn't work, because the first array got mingled while the other one didn't. So I wrote a general multidimensional array case insensitive compare function. It also can use multiple keys:

```
function array_casecmp($keys) {
    if (gettype($keys) != "array") $keys = func_get_args();
    return function ($a, $b) use ($keys) {
        foreach($keys as $value) {
            $akeys = $akeys . $a[$value];
            $bkeys = $bkeys . $b[$value];
        }
        return strcasecmp($akeys, $bkeys);
    };
}
```

Use it like:

```
usort($files,strcasecmp(array(0,1)); // with standard array
usort($files,strcasecmp(1); // single key
usort($files,strcasecmp(0,1); // arguments are converted to array
usort($files,strcasecmp("dir","link")); // you can also use symbolic keys
usort($files,strcasecmp(0,1,2,3,4,...); // use as many keys as you like
```

Keep in mind that the keys are concatenated, so maybe you have to use str_pad in your array colums to keep them seperated in the right way.